# add url parameters to $_GET variable with separated commas issue

Tags: php, url

This is my function, I simply want to output a link like this:

```
www.example.com/new?cat=22,23,27
```

If a category value already exists I want to delete it. If it doesn't exist yet, i want to add it.

This is my function:

```
function setorunset($value) {
    if(isset($_GET['cat'])) { //wenn schon eine categorie da ist
        if(strpos($value,$_GET['cat']) === false ) { 
            $_GET['cat'] .= ",".$value; }
        else {
            str_replace(",".$value, ",", $_GET['cat']);
        }
        echo http_build_query($_GET);   
    }
    else {
        echo http_build_query($_GET).'&cat='.$value;
    }
}
```

I simply can't find the error why this shouldnt work:
I call this function with:
 setorunset(22);

Does anyone find any error?

Comment: add some information. e.g. the output of `var_dump($_GET)` so we can see what happens. Also - `I simply cant find the error why this shouldnt work` What error? What is the output?

Comment: Hi, if i click on the link more than once it always adds a 22 : www.example.com/?cat=22,22,22,22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `strpos()` for this. If you have `cat=101,11` and you call `setorunset(10)` it will match the `10` in `101`.

Instead, use `explode()` to create an array from the value, update the array, and then use `implode()` to create the new value.

```
function setorunset($value) {
    if(isset($_GET['cat'])) { //wenn schon eine categorie da ist
        $cat = explode(',', $_GET['cat']);
        $pos = array_search($value, $cat);
        if ($pos === false) {
            $cat[] = $value;
        } else {
            unset($cat[$pos]);
        }
        $_GET['cat'] = implode(',', $cat);
    }
    else {
        $_GET['cat'] = $value;
    }
    echo http_build_query($_GET);
}
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is, is that if i add the function twice in my page, for more than one link it adds 22 two times - www.example.com/?cat=2222

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `,` in `implode`.

Comment: Sorry, if i call this function with different values on the same page, it will add all values to the GET variable. like i call setorunset(22) it will echo /?cat=22 , if i call setorunset(23) the line after it will echo /?cat=22,23 BUT it should echo /?cat=23 instead. Any suggestions? Sorry a plus to my question above ;)

Comment: You said if the category already exists it should be removed, if it doesn't exist it should be added. So that's the correct behavior.